# How to select a named range in Google Sheets' query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to set up a query using named ranges, is it possible to select a named range within a query?

I've tried the following:

```
=QUERY(NamedRange, "select '"&NamedRange2&"' where '"&NamedRange3&"' contains '"&B2&"' ")
```

I want to be able to use named ranges instead of having to use `select A where...`or `select col1 where...` since the spreadsheet is constantly going through revisions where columns change so I want to keep the query dynamic so it doesn't constantly need updating.

Comment: Something like [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33840/45867) or  [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87895/45867)?

Answer (score 1):

partially. you can have it like this:

```
=QUERY({NamedRange}, "select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&B2&"'")
```